# Contenttools how to make an area not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container div in which everything is editable

```
<div data-editable data-name="main-content">

</div>
```

Which works fine as expected, but inside of that div there are multiple sections which all can be edited as well (due to the parent div having the editable tag) but I want to have a section (a p tag) that isn't editable whilst all the other content in that div is editable.

Apart from removing data-editable from the parent div and adding it to each individual p tag (to which there could be hundreds or even thousands) how do I block just one p tag from being editable?

I would think there is a tag like data-none-editable but I can't find anything in the docs unless I'm missing the obvious.

EDIT:

For clarification the library I'm using (as per the title) is ContentTools which can be found here: http://getcontenttools.com/

Comment: does `contenteditable="false"` on your html attribute work? from this (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

Comment: You're missing some important information. What plugin are you using?

Comment: @evolutionxbox as in the title Contenttools

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you still face problem please let me know

```css
.first{
   height: 300px;
   border:1px solid red;
  }
  .wrapper{
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .second{
   background-color: green; 
   width:200px; 
   height: 100px;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 10px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div contenteditable="true" data-name="main-content" class="first">

</div>
<div  contenteditable="false" class="second">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is still facing the problem.

Comment: Can you please post full html so I checkout what you want ?